# What is a good off the shelf tablet or open-frame device that runs or can run Android for use as a Kiosk/POS

Tags: android, tablet, touchscreen

I'm looking for an Android touch screen device that would make a good UI for a Kiosk/POS terminal.

The system will be locked down and should run a reasobably recent Android release (ideally Android 7+)

Either the device should have ongoing manufacturer support so that future android releases are available.

Or the possibility of 'bake your own' where there is good community support for building stock android for the device.

As it will be built into a kiosk, it could be an open frame design or some sort of tablet, ideally rugged as it will get a lot of use.

Screen size about 14" but larger is ok.  Fancy features not needed.

Comment: You couldn't find useful tags as you asked this on our Meta. I have migrated this to our main site and added relevant tags. Please review and [edit] your question if I have missed anything.

Comment: Have you thought about using a Raspberry Pi with a touch screen monitor rather than a tablet? This would give you the benefit of running whatever OS and software needed, and would be cheaper and easier to replace than a tablet.

Comment: @Cfinley I'm actually going to strongly disagree with using a Pi here. Most exiting POS software, e.g. Square, Revel, or Toast (which is what I assume is what will be used here) is designed to run on iOS or Android. On that note, have you chosen a POS software, or are you still open to suggestions?

Comment: I have under two weeks to deliver a working proof of concept, so weant for Pi and a 10" touchscreen, but the future product is still open to suggestions.  I like the idea of using Android but failed to find anyting suitable.